# How can Include both commonJs require syntax and es modules import syntax in the same bundle - webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, commonjs

before tagging as a duplicate, I searched for an answer before I asked and I found this one:
[Is it possible to use both "require" and "import" together with Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068126/is-it-possible-to-use-both-require-and-import-together-with-webpack)

The problem is that the accepted answer directs to the webpack documentation which has different content now.

### The issue:

I have a project with Webpack version `4.41.2`, React as a front and approximately 600 js/jsx files all written with the old `require` and `module.exports` syntax and I want to update them to the `import/export` syntax (not all of them at one time because this will take forever). When I try to update even one simple file like this:

From this-

```
const React = require('react');

const Spinner = () => {
    return (
        <div className="vertical-align" style={{ "width": "100%", "height": "100%" }}>
            <div className="lds-ring">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

module.exports = Spinner;
```

To this-

```
import React from 'react';

const Spinner = () => {
    return (
        <div className="vertical-align" style={{ "width": "100%", "height": "100%" }}>
            <div className="lds-ring">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Spinner;
```

The app gets crashed and It gives me the following errors:
[image]

ContactList is the component that renders the Spinner component.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
"use strict";
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = [
    {
        mode: 'development',
        context: __dirname + "/app",
        entry: {
            'app': ["./main.jsx"],
            'widget': ["./Widget/Widget.jsx"],
            'admin': ["./Admin/Main.jsx"],
            'dashboard': ["./Dashboard/Main.jsx"],
            'signin': ["./SignIn/Main.jsx"],
            'surveys': ["./Surveys/Main.jsx"]
        },
        output: {
            filename: "[name].entry.js",
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            publicPath: '/'
        },
        devtool: "eval-source-map",
        devServer: {
            hot: true,
            contentBase: './dist',
            host: "localhost",
            inline: true,
            port: 58852
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    use: ['babel-loader'],
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/i,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
        ],
        performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 10000000,
            maxAssetSize: 10000000
        }
    }
]
```

I will be extremely thankful for any suggestion of how can I solve this problem.

Comment: How do you use `Spinner ` in `ContactList`? Something like `const Spinner = require('./path/to/Spinner')`?

Comment: @chenxsan yes, I do it this way

Comment: Will `const {default: Spinner} = require('./path/to/Spinner')` fix your problem? If yes, you might need https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports.

Comment: @Ran Regarding your suggested edits, Stack Snippets are great, but I'd highly recommend not adding unnecessary leading indentation in the process. If it's hard to do manually, consider pressing the "Tidy" button.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for the feedback. How can I use the "Tidy" button?

Comment: You just press it, and the snippet will automatically be tidied. It's [not perfect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/401909) but it'll work for most posts.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how the latest babel works when transpiling es module to commonjs.

Take this code for example:

```
const Spinner = () => {
    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};

export default Spinner;
```

Babel will [transpile it](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAygBwJZjAUwE4wLwwBQCUOAfDAN4BQM1MGaUArhmPlTewDwAmSAbsRwD0Pfm2oEA3BQC-UimgAeCEBlhc0AMwCGDADaxEKdBglA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.12&externalPlugins=) into:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = void 0;

var Spinner = function Spinner() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null);
};

var _default = Spinner;
exports.default = _default;
```

As you can see from the transpiled code above, there's no `module.exports`, only `exports.default`, that means you have to use `const {default: Spinner} = require('./path/to/Spinner')` instead of `const Spinner = require('./path/to/Spinner')`.

But sure you can work around it with help of https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports.